# AWS Elastic Beanstalk .NET App's file not changing after upload and deploy

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server-2019

I created an AWS Beanstalk app and choose "Sample application" while creating. The app runs perfectly.

But later I followed this documentation [Deploying an ASP.NET Core application with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html#dotnet-core-tutorial-update) and uploaded, deployed my own files, but the app remains the same. There is no change and if I go to the URL, I see that sample application. I went to **Application versions** and deleted old versions, reuploaded my files, nothing changes.

Any solution? Why is this happening and what should I have to do?

- My app written on ASP .NET Core 3.1
- My Beanstalk platform is IIS 10.0, 64bit Windows Server 2019/2.5.6

Comment: Have you inspected log files? They should provide some insights if there are any errors.

Comment: Log files all are ok and green.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to simply launch a new environment with your own application, rather then trying to replace the sample one.

Comment: Have you checked inside the EC2 instance for those changes? Also, recycle the current Site?